# COUNT of sql SELECT query with LIMIT in mySQL

Tags: php, sql, select, count, limit

In php-mysql, how to count number of rows returned within a SELECT query?
let's think of the `SELECT` query something like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * from users LIMIT 20,60"
```

But if total number of records was just for example 55, The results is users from 20 to 55 with a total number of 35 not 40!
How can I have the number 35 without querying the DB twice?
now I am doing like this:

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) from users LIMIT 20, 60";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $1);
$count = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $count[0];
```

But here I am querying the DB twice and I think this is not so good.
I know that I could have the total number of rows without considering the `LIMIT`, using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()`, but this is not my case, as I want to consider the `LIMIT`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to [num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it and accept you answer. but is this the same az `mysqli_num_rows($result);` ?

Comment: Yup. According to the page: Object oriented style -- int $mysqli_result->num_rows; Procedural style -- int mysqli_num_rows ( mysqli_result $result )

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) from users LIMIT 20, 60";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $1);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

mysqli_num_rows() returns no. of rows

Comment: Thanks! does your answer the same result as anyber's answer? I mean `$result->num_rows`.

Comment: i think in your case my answer is perfect, because anyber's answer is for Object oriented query